# Minecraft Enchanting Power

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a certain pattern needed for enchantment tables so they get much more powerful since I tried bookshelves and the enchantments aren't much more powerful.

Comment: This is the second minecraft question you've asked today, and both could have been very easily googled

Comment: wait should i delete this then?

Comment: no do not delete this, as it now serves as an additional avenue for searchers to find their answer to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bookshelves need to be placed no more than two blocks away from the enchanting table horizontally, and must be vertically either on the same level as the table, or one level up.

Bookshelves increase the number of levels you can dump into an enchantment, increasing the chances that the enchantment you get is a good one. 15 bookshelves caps this effect.

It should look like this when finished.

[image: Bookshelf Pattern]